# The use of librosa.effects.trim to remove the silent part in audio

Tags: machine-learning, audio, deep-learning, librosa

I am doing a speech emotion recognition ML.

I currently use `pyAudioAnalysis` to do a multi-directory feature extraction. However, the dataset involved in audios containing a lot of approximately silent sections. My objective is to remove the approximately silent parts from all the audios then extract meaningful features.

My current approach is to use `librosa` to trim the silent parts.

```
from librosa.effects import trim
import librosa
from pyAudioAnalysis import audioBasicIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

signal, Fs = librosa.load(file_directory)
trimed_signal = trim(signal,top_db=60)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
librosa.display.waveplot(trimed_signal, sr=Fs, ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set(title='Monophonic')
ax[0].label_outer()
```

I tried to plot the wave after trimming using `librosa.display.waveplot` but an AttributeError occurred showing  `AttributeError: module 'librosa' has no attribute 'display'`

My questions are

1. How to plot the trimmed wave?
2. Is it possible to generate a trimmed .wav  file? This is because `pyAudioAnalysis`'s input for feature extraction is .wav file path but the output of `librosa` is array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to `import librosa.display` separately. See [this issue](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/343) for the reason.
2. You can use `librosa.output.write_wav` (check [the docs](https://librosa.org/doc/0.7.2/generated/librosa.output.write_wav.html)) to store the trimmed array as a wave file. E.g. `librosa.output.write_wav(path, trimed_signal, Fs)`.

Comment: Sadly librosa has removed the output function. I tried using pysoundfile but it popped error that `ValueError: dtype must be one of ['float32', 'float64', 'int16', 'int32']`

Comment: I managed to install an earlier version of librosa which contains the output function but it gave me similar error:`ParameterError: Audio data must be of type numpy.ndarray`

Comment: What dtype does the data that you are passing have?

Comment: Since librosa 0.8.0 the output functions are removed, one should use soundfile instead https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#soundfile.write